# Get trigger from element

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

So I have this problem. I want to data trigger a column visibility for a grid in a WPF, but I can't get to bind the property name from the view with the actual property from the ViewModel.

View looks like this:

```
<Page x:Class="ImageViewer.Pages.ImageViewPage">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ColumnDefinition  x:Name="SidePanelColumn">
        <ColumnDefinition.Style>                    
            <Style TargetType="ColumnDefinition">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="250"/>
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="250"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" x:Name="SidePanelColumnVisibility" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ColumnDefinition.Style>
    </ColumnDefinition>
```

The binding is done like this (for other properties):

```
 this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.AppCursor, v => v.Cursor).DisposeWith(cleanup);
```

here we bind the property name AppCursor from the ViewModel with the property Cursor from the View.

I would like to do the same with `SidePanelColumnVisibility`. My problem is that I can't seem to be able to access SidePanelColumnVisibility from the View.

The biding should look something like

```
this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.SidebarVisible, v => v.SidePanelColumnVisibility).DisposeWith(cleanup);
```

`this.SidePanelColumn.Style.Triggers` when inspecting this element I can see my trigger, but can't find a way to get the trigger by it's name SidePanelColumnVisibility.

I am fairly new to WPF ( been doing it for a week). I for sure somewhere misunderstood something, any help would be great.

LE:

The column looks like this

```
 <ListBox Grid.Column="0" 
                 MinWidth="250" 
                 x:Name="FrameListBox" 
                 BorderThickness="0" 
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="1"></UniformGrid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image MinWidth="200" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Source ="{Binding}" Stretch="Uniform"></Image>
                </DataTemplate>
           </ListBox.ItemTemplate>         
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to set the width of a columndefinition through a binding like this? An easier approach would be to set the column definition width to Auto then hide elements in the column. How many elements do you have in the column you are trying to hide.

Comment: As I was saying, why is not a good question. It was my first solution. The column is a ListBox of images.@AndrewMurphy I've added the column, hope it helps.

Comment: @NawedNabiZada this won't help me, I don't want to bind it in the XML, i want the bind to be done behind on strongly typed properties.

Comment: Why do you want to do the binding in Code behind? [Perhaps an MVVM tutorial might help you understand how to use bindings effectively](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvvm/index.htm)

Comment: The question is more related to reactiveui rather than wpf. It uses code behind bindings mostly for compile time errors if property names changes and also global converter registrations. I often see people get confused on here thinking it's a direct wpf question and would suggest people move away from that.

Comment: See https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/data-binding/ for further details for those confused why the op is asking about code behind bindings.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to use rxui bindings on the sidecar visibility. You can create a new control for your images you want to display and use rxui bindings there. Essentially doing what others have recommended here but in a rxui way.

Comment: You could try setting the visibility of the listbox itself and set the width of the column that contains it set to "auto", then bind to FrameListBox in the code-behind. Not sure if the visual will look good but maybe worth a shot :)

Comment: @GlennWatson I've managed to do it by biding 2 proprieties. One sets the ListBox visibility to Hidden and the other one that sets the Width of the column to 0 or back to the original value.